# Изменение типа JSON

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, есть json вида:

```
[{"PAN":"1234"},{"PAN":"123456789"}]
```

Необходимо получить:

```
["1234","123456789"]
```

Как это можно сделать в php?

Comment: array_column или, если версия не позволяет, array_map

Answer (score 1):

Оказался за компом в развитие комментария

```
echo json_encode((array_column(json_decode($json1,true),'PAN')));
```

или преобразуйте исходный массив так:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($i) { return $i['PAN']; }, json_decode($json1,true)));
```